# How to Make Navigation bar on top of carousel?

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel, navigationbar

I just recently added a Carousel on my portfolio website. However, the carousel is overlapping the navigation bar when I scroll down (its on top of it).

[image]

[image]

My Code

Navbar.js:

```
...
return (        
    <nav class="header">
      <ul class="list">
        <li className='item'>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className='item'>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li className='item'>
          <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
        </li>
        <li className='item'>
          <Link to="/contact">Contact Me</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
)
```

Navbar.css:

```
.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #3D405B;
    width: 100%;
}
...
```

Home.js

```
const skills = DataSkills.map(skill => {
    return <Card
        key={skill.id}
        skill={skill} />
})

const responsive = {
    superLargeDesktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
        items: 5
    },
    desktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
        items: 4
    },
    tablet: {
        breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
        items: 2
    },
    mobile: {
        breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
        items: 1
    }
};

return (
    <Carousel responsive={responsive} className='home--skills-list'>
        {skills}
    </Carousel>
)
```

Home.css:

```
.home--skills-list {

}
```

None of the other Cards, images, and text are overlapping the navigation bar, just the carousel. Since that is the case, I assume that I don't have to change anything in the navigation bar, and only on the carousel (please correct me if I'm wrong on that). How do I make it so that the carousel is not overlapping the navigation bar?

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want the navigation bar to go above the carousel right? If so, you should set a z-index for the navigation bar that is higher than the z-index of the carousel. Because the higher the z-index of an element, the higher (more in the foreground) it will appear.

```
.header{
...
z-index: 1000;

}
```

And then on the carousel have a z-index of less than that. But I'm not sure if that's even neccesarry then. I may have misunderstood the problem if so then I'm happy to help :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to set a position value on the carousel to put a Z-index there. Just in case it is not fixed by setting the Z-index on the navigation bar

Comment: Works!! This literally a one line solution. Thank you! Now I know what a Z-index is

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to the navigation top of the carousel with sticky. if so you can use  react-bootstrap. easily you can make navigation with sticky

Comment: Just for future refence, this would have been a perfectly acceptable comment but it doesn't quite fit the parameters of being a respectable solution.  Considering the OP spent the time divulging their code, it would be recommended to respond back within the context of said code with a solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).